# How can I filter emails gmail and hotmail and . . . by python

Tags: python

Please help this is my problem and thank you.
How can I make a filter by python, for example, I want to make a list.txt and input in list emails like

```
x@gmail and x@yahoo and x@outlook
```

After that, I'll run script python and it filter emails in list.txt
Gmail alone and Yahoo alone and outlook alone.
Please help and thank you very much

Comment: Filter by `mail.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]`

Comment: Welcome to SO: you may want to read [ask] and [mcve].